# Geometry column of new feature is not stored

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers-2

```
var saveStrategy2 = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vectors", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy2],
    protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        url : baseurl + "/wfs",
        version : "1.1.0",
        featureType : "myLayername",
        featureNS : "myWorkspace",
        srsName : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");,

    }),
    renderers : ["Canvas"],

});




map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {

    var latitude = position.lat;
    var longitude = position.lon;


    var marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(longitude, latitude), {
        draggable : true,
        name : "myName",
    }, {
        externalGraphic : url_to_png,
        graphicHeight : 50,
        graphicWidth : 50,
        graphicXOffset : -25,
        graphicYOffset : -50
    });

    vectorLayer.addFeatures([marker]);
    marker.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;

    saveStrategy2.save([marker]);

}
```

a click leads to the following wfs

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<wfs:Insert>
<feature:myLayername xmlns:feature="myWorkspace">
<feature:null>
<gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
<gml:pos>13.433522343635467 52.4206938584817</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</feature:null>
<feature:draggable>true</feature:draggable>
<feature:name>myName</feature:name>
</feature:myLayername>
</wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

especially `<feature:null>` looks weird. In other Layers, this is usually `<feature:geom>`

Eventually, the corresponding database cell `geom` does not get the expected geometrical value, nut NULL instead, while the column `name`gets the correct value `myName`

Answer (score 1):

solved myself:

added `geometryName: "geom"` in the WFS constructor.

(Still don't know why this is necessary for this layer only).